# How to inject custom css in wbeview

Tags: android, html, css, webview, android-webview

I'm trying to add custom css to webview content in android application but it does not show any effect in webview may be it has not been added successfully.

My custom font css :

```
/* normal */
@font-face {
   font-family: 'PT_Sans-Web';
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: 400;
   src: local('PT_Sans Web Regular'), local('PT_Sans-Web-Regular'),url(file:///android_asset/fonts/PT_Sans-Web-Regular.ttf);
}

/* bold */
@font-face {
   font-family: 'PT_Sans-Web';
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: 700;
   src: local('PT_Sans Web Bold'), local('PT_Sans-Web-Bold'), url(file:///android_asset/fonts/PT_Sans-Web-Bold.ttf);
 }
```

style.css

```
body {
font-family: PT_Sans-Web;
color: #4DB2EC;
font-size: 15pt;
width: 100%;
background: #fff;
}

strong {
font-weight: bold;
}

embed,object,img{display: block; max-width:100%; height: auto;}
.frame {width: 100%} 
#templates{display:none}
.subs-loading {width: 90%; margin: 2em auto; font-size: 1.5em; }
#subscriptions {
position: relative;
}

#container {
padding: 16px;
}

p {
font-family: PT_Sans-Web;
color: #4DB2EC;
font-size: 7pt;
width: 100%;
background: #fff;
line-height:11.38pt
}

h1 {
font-size: 2em;
line-height: 1.2em;
font-weight: bold;
color: #222;
margin: .1em 0 .2em;
}
```

Loading code in webview :

```
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(
            "file:///android_asset/",
            content,
            "text/html",
            "utf-8",
            null);
string content = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset='UTF-8' />"
            + "<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>"
            + "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='pt_sans.css'>"
            + "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='webview.css'>"
            + "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css\">"
            + "</head><body>"
            + mPostContent
            + "</body></html>";
```

I'm using webview with webChromeclient. But this doesn't show any effect in webview. Is am I doing wrong. Which is better way to add css in webview.

On opening webview I'm getting this error in log :

```
E/libEGL: validate_display:99 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
```

This error gives on testing device nexus 5x and working properly on another devices.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `css` file into `assets` folder and then address it in the `html`. Update your `content` variable like this:

```
string content = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset='UTF-8' />"
        + "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"file:///android_asset/style.css\">" //<-- Add this line
        + //...
```

Comment: It working in one plus testing device with android 6 but giving this error "E/libEGL: validate_display:99 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)" in nexus 5x with android version 7

Comment: I don't know about the error, but it obviously is related to OpenGL and is out of your hand. I think you should ignore it.